# Android:How to send more than 1 variable with Intent?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-studio-2.2

Am sending a few variables from `main.java`:

```
    Bundle bund = new Bundle();
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, newWindow.class);
    String name = editName.getText().toString();
    bund.putString(yourName, name);
    String pass= editPassword.getText().toString();
    bund.putString(yourPass,pass);
    String mail=EditMail.getText().toString();
    bund.putString(yourMail,mail);
    intent.putExtras(bund);
    startActivity(intent);
```

to `newWindow.java`:

```
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        Bundle extras =  intent.getExtras();
           String name = extras.getString(main.yourName);
           String mail = extras.getString(main.yourMail);
           String pass = extras.getString(main.yourPass);
        viewText1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        viewText2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        viewText3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
        viewText1.setText(name);
        viewText2.setText(mail);
        viewText3.setText(pass);
```

**The problem is, only last variable is passed and showed in all 3 textview's**

Comment: The real takeaway here: if you dont understand that "", "", and "" are the **same** string; and that using those three strings as keys to a map result in only **one** value being put in there; then well, you should stop doing android for some time. Instead you should read some tutorials on the java basics. Otherwise you are **doomed** to run into one "strange" problem after the other; because, sorry, but you have no clue what you are doing.

Comment: And just for the record: class names start uppercase in java; always.

Answer (score 4):

Presumably, you are using the same key in all cases. In other words, your value of `yourName` is the same as the value of `yourPass`, which is the same as the value of `yourMail`. These need to have unique values. Usually, we use `static final String` keys for `Bundle`.

Comment: in main. java i have declared
    `public final static String yourName = "";`
    `public final static String yourPass="";`
    `public final static String yourMail="";`

Comment: @Darius92: Those are all the same. You need to change them to be different, such as `public final static String yourName = "yourName";` and so on.

Comment: Great catch ... !

Answer (score 1):

Why not avoid the Bundle part ?

Simply in the FirstActivity, try this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, NewWindow.class);
String name = editName.getText().toString();
String pass= editPassword.getText().toString();
String mail=EditMail.getText().toString();
intent.putExtra("name",name);
intent.putExtra("mail",mail);
intent.putExtra("pass",pass);
startActivity(intent);
```

Then in RecievingActivity do this

```
Intent extras=getIntent();
String name = extras.getStringExtra("name");
String mail = extras.getStringExtra("mail");
String pass = extras.getStringExtra("pass");
viewText1.setText(name);
viewText2.setText(mail);
viewText3.setText(pass);
```

Let me know if it helps